# Could not find property supportLibraryDependency

Tags: android, zxing

I want to use ZXing barcode Scanner library in my project but I got an error

```
Error:(12, 0) Could not find property 'supportLibraryDependency' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@207a9938.
```

and this is core build.gradle where supportLibraryDependency is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

ext {
    isLibrary = true
    pomPackaging = "aar"
    pomArtifactId = "core"
    pomName = "Barcode Scanner View"
    pomDescription = 'An android library project which contains the core barcode scanner view'
}

dependencies {
    compile supportLibraryDependency
}
```

please help

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
compile supportLibraryDependency
```

with

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```